# How create ISessionFactory with FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In a project MyProject.Data, I have a folder named mappings with all mapping in.

```
namespace MyProject.Data.Mappings {
    public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.FirstName).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
            Map(x => x.LastName).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
        }
    } }
```

In the MVC project, in the web.config :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="db" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

In the global.asax.cs, I'd like create the ISessionFactory :

```
var nhConfig = Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
   .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("db")))
   .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<?????>())
   .BuildConfiguration();
ISessionFactory SessionFactory = nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I need a :
`.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<?????>())` for each mapping file ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that serves that purpose of telling FNH which assembly to look for all your mappings. Just specify any one and you are good to go.

So, the code below will work for you if all your mappings live in the same assembly.

```
var nhConfig = Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("db")))
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EmployeeMap>())
.BuildConfiguration();
```

Comment: you mean replace "????" by MyProject.Data.Mappings.EmployeeMap and will be ok for all other mapping ?

Comment: @Kris-I Yes, if all of your mappings will be in the same assembly (most likely if they are all in the same project) then specifying one of the types will cause that assembly to be loaded, all the types read, and all the fluent mappings to be added dynamically.